# JQ / JQM show menu when tap&hold button

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-mobile, slide

Iam trying to realize a menu which is opened via a button. So far, easy. The core difference is, that it is not just simply opening, I want to be able to hold that button and move the menu in. Like you probably know from native applications, you touch the a menu button which is a left side, hold it and while you are moving it to the right, the menu is already showing.

To see it in live: Facebook App on iPad (not sure on iPhone), you can switch on/off the menu with a button, but you can also hold the button and move right/left <-- this is exactly the function Iam trying to realize.

Btw. the JQM 'taphold' function could be used, but how to realize the menu showing..

[image: Screenshot]

how could I realize this?

Comment: http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-horizontal-accordion/ This example of a Horizontal Accordion is what you might want to look into. You will have to create a custom one but this should give you the idea to start

Comment: thanks phil but I think there's a difference between your hint and my idea. the horizontal accordion uses in my opinion fade/slide or anything else to move, I dont know how to get this reaction (visible text of the accordion) when clickHold an move the mouse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bgjNM/15/), I think that it is what you want.

Comment: edit: I can work with this, waiting for another solution and additionally a method how to enable one single div to scroll, but disbale it for the page =) its now only working with JQM 'vtouchmove'.. im on it =) GOOD HINT!!

Comment: if you set `overflow: auto;` in css on one specific div it will be scroll-able if there is more content in then it fit in and if you set `overflow: scroll;` in css on one specific div it will be scroll-able all the time (if that is what you want)

Comment: thanks, I realized it with JQM's 'vmousemove'. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I'm trying to use with JQM but it doesn't work for me with binding the 'vmousemove' event  ... could anybody update the exemple or tell me how to update it for JQM? Thx